# ValidationError with Django REST API and generic_relations for generic foreign key writable access

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, generic-foreign-key, generic-relations

I'm using Django REST API and [generic_relations](https://github.com/Ian-Foote/rest-framework-generic-relations) module with it to create a kind of variant to Django Comments which is not driven by templates but via REST API functions.

The Model class in named Annotation and is like:

```
class Annotation(BaseCommentAbstractModel):

    paragraph_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False)

    body = models.TextField()
    '''
    Annotations can be written only by logged in users. It is to prevent hit and run comments by people under anonymity.
    '''
    user = models.ForeignKey(DjangoUser, null=False, verbose_name=_('user'), related_name = "annotations")
```

Now, there is another model, for content, which can be pretty much anything, so lets say, it is a simple Posting Application:

```
class BlogContent(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    body = models.TextField()
    ...
    annotation = GenericRelation(Annotation, content_type_field='content_type', object_id_field='object_pk')
```

The serializers for the same look like:

```
from generic_relations.relations import GenericRelatedField 

class BlogContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author_id = serializers.Field(source='author_id.username')
    annotation = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = BlogContent
        fields = ('title','created','author_id',
              'data','published_flag', 'url_path','slug','annotation')

class AnnotationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.Field(source='user.username')
    content_object = GenericRelatedField({
        BlogContent: serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='annotation:blogcontent-detail'),
        }, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Annotation
        fields = ('paragraph_id', 'body', 'user', 'content_object')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    blogcontent= serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True) 
    annotations = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'id', 'blogcontent', 'annotations')
```

Now, the problem is in the line:
    content_object = GenericRelatedField({
            BlogContent: serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='annotation:blogcontent-detail'),
            }, read_only=False)

If the generic relations are to be used as read only, by setting the `read_only=True`, then the REST API browsability is fine, but the moment I switch it to `False`, the server throws back a ValidationError

```
ValidationError at /en/annotation/
[u'Invalid model - model not available.']
```

Perusing the logs and the code, it seems that in `rest_framework.renderers.py` at `get_raw_data_form(self, view, method, request)` Does not find an object in the call `obj = getattr(view, 'object', None)`.

This in turn, while evaluating `field_to_native` function as `serializer = self.determine_deserializer_for_data(value)` in `generic_relations`,  causes to pass nothing in as `value` and hence, the code breaks.

Has anybody else too encountered such error and/or could help me fix it? Please help!

The traceback is as follows:

```
/home/craft/pirateenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
            response = response.render() ...
▶ Local vars
/home/craft/pirateenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py in render
        self.content = self.rendered_content ...
▶ Local vars
/home/craft/pirateenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, media_type, context) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/craft/pirateenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py in render
    context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/craft/pirateenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py in get_context
    raw_data_post_form = self.get_raw_data_form(view, 'POST', request) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/craft/pirateenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py in get_raw_data_form
            content = renderer.render(serializer.data, accepted, context) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/craft/pirateenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py in data
            self._data = self.to_native(obj) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/craft/pirateenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py in to_native
        value = field.field_to_native(obj, field_name) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/craft/pirateenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/generic_relations/relations.py in field_to_native
    serializer = self.determine_deserializer_for_data(value) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/craft/pirateenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/generic_relations/relations.py in determine_deserializer_for_data
        raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['no_model_match']) ...
▶ Local vars
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This issue on the repository](https://github.com/Ian-Foote/rest-framework-generic-relations/issues/3) also mentions the same error but in a different context, the solution offered, nevertheless works for me too, until the time the author releases a fix.

The solution is to add an  `if value:` clause after calling the `super` method.